# Is optimization necessary when code generation is targeting a runtime with JIT?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, code-generation

I'm planning on writing a programming language targeting the .NET platform which led me to start thinking about the code generation aspect of targeting such a platform. I'm new at writing compilers but I know there is optimization done as one of the phases in compiling (or there can be). I started to wonder about the any benefit to spending time optimizing the output (in this case CIL but this would apply to the JVM too) because the JIT compiler and things like the JVM's HotSpot could optimize at run time. Is there any benefit from optimizing the generated code (CIL or the JVM equivalent) when targeting .NET or JVM since the JIT will already optimize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. There are countless optimizations. Any given compiler (your compiler, the JIT compiler, or any other compiler) necessarily implements only a subset of those. This choice depends on available time, typical/expected input code, priorities, etc. and therefore the engineers who built the JIT compiler may have selected optimizations which work well for the programs they were expecting, but not so well for the kind of program you care about.

You will have to determine what optimizations the JIT compiler misses. The way to do this is, of course, empirical: Actually write programs, letting the JIT compiler optimize them (be sure to do this part properly - disable debugging, compile for release, choose realistic benchmarks, etc.), and then inspect the final machine code. Look for unexpected code (you will, of course, need assembly knowledge for this) and determine if it's a missed optimization or if the JIT was smarter than you thought.

If it is a missed optimization, you have another problem: You can't output the machine code you want, you have to generate different IL instead.
A missed optimization is *probably* due to a language feature the VM doesn't know (e.g. multi methods on the JVM). You lowered it into the VM's terms during compilation but the translation you chose doesn't sit well with the JIT's order of passes, heuristics, etc.
As you can't just output machine code yourself, you must now find an alternative IL fragment for the same input language code. Ideally, one which the JIT compiler does handle well. Finding that may be an exercise in imagination, but it's not technically hard, just guesswork interleaved with benchmarking.

As another answer points out, JIT compilers work under time constraints. This *may* lead to optimizations that *could* happen being missed (e.g. constant propagation running out of time), but as the creators of the JIT compiler faced the same problem, this probably isn't too severe if you don't create *much* larger/more complicated code.
**If** you create such bad code that the JIT compiler can't fix it all, then you have to duplicate its optimizations in your AOT compiler. I'm not convinced that this is a likely scenario though, and even if it happens even very simple optimizations should mostly fix the problem.

So, **in summary**: Start with a straightforward translation, then seek out missed optimizations and either make it easier to optimize for the JIT compiler, or do it yourself (if possible - adaptive optimization is much harder in an AOT setting).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is hard to answer in general.

For example, the F# compiler performs a [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call_optimization), because having tail-recursive functions is common in that language, the F# compiler can do a better job at optimizing them in some cases than the JIT compiler and some versions of the JIT compiler don't perform the optimization at all.

So, your language might have some common operation whose straightforward implementation wouldn't perform well. In that case, it makes sense emitting IL code that's optimized.

What I think you should do is the same as when you're writing a normal program: first write your code in a way that is simple and readable. Only if something doesn't perform well, attempt to optimize that. It might be worth considering that you might need some optimizations in the future and make your code modular enough, so that you don't have to rewrite half of it because of some optimization. But for now, that should be enough.

Writing a compiler is hard enough job already (even if you're targeting an IL). Finish it first and think about optimizations later.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You make a good point about language specific optimizations that wouldn't be done in the JIT, it is definitely something I didn't think about.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, JIT compilers have some thresholds governing how much optimization they will attempt to perform.  These may be based on the size of a method's IL and/or the amount of time already spent JIT compiling the method.  So yes, IL which has already been optimized **may** benefit from further JIT optimization.  As always, there is a trade-off: how much time do you want to spend adding AOT optimizations to your compiler (and testing/maintaining them) versus how quickly your code can be JIT compiled, and with what level of optimization.

The magnitude of the improvement depends largely on how much simpler (and smaller) the AOT-optimized IL is relative to the unoptimized IL, as well as the thresholds governing the JIT compiler (which, at least for the Microsoft CLR, are not widely known).  The only way to find out is to do some testing yourself.